# Is "sleep" stative or dynamic

Tags: verbs, stative-verbs, dynamic-verbs

*Sleep* means to rest your mind and body, usually at night. So it should be stative. But we often say something like "I am sleeping". So it looks also like a dynamic verb. Is *sleep* stative or dynamic or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think of the names of the categories quite so literally. The [University of Victoria's Study Zone](https://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/courses/elc/studyzone/410/grammar/stat.htm) specifically lists "sleep" as a dynamic verb, and from the description it should be pretty clear why:

- > Dynamic verbs (sometimes referred to as "action verbs") usually describe actions we can take, or things that happen
- > [S]tative verbs usually refer to a state or condition which is not changing or likely to change.
- > The difference is important, because stative verbs cannot normally be used in the continuous (BE + ING) forms.

Comment: I agree that *sleep* is dynamic for *sleep* is a process which is stationary. But why *stand* and *sit* are stative?

Comment: @MathWizard I don't believe they are stative, at least not in the senses I'm thinking of.

Comment: I have seen from online sources that *stand, sit* and *lie* are stative, while *lay* is dynamic. I agree with it particularly for *sit* which is really like stative. But it may be inclusive because "I am sitting in the sofa" and "I am standing in the line" sound ok

Comment: Every single stative verb in English can be used in the progressive. Even the most the stative of all verbs *to be*: Harry is being so kind today. Use these categories as an aid to understanding but nothing more.

Comment: You really have to scramble semantically when you use some stative predicates in the progressive: _??Bill is being so tall today._ *_This group is being non-Abelian._